# Laravel - convert input date format before save

Tags: laravel-4, php-carbon

I'm trying to convert date input to the proper mysql format.
My start_date field is formatted MM dd, yyyy.

In my controller store function I'm grabbing all the users input including start_date and saving.

```
$userProfileData->save();
```

What I thought I could do is us Carbon to convert the start_date before save like this.

```
$userProfileData->start_date->toDateString();
```

I get a Call to a member function toDateString() on a non-object error.

Comment: I was able to figure this out. $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($userProfileData->start_date));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to convert the date format by adding this to my users controller store function.

```
$userProfileData->start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($userProfileData->start_date));
```

Answer (score 4):

you get non-object error because start_date is not the object with method toDateString()

what you can do is use setStartDateAttribute() method in your model which will be invoked every time to get the start_date attribute value and in this method you can modify value so model will use the updated value for operation like edit or update it can be as follow

```
public function setStartDateAttribute($value) {
      $this->attributes['start_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value) );
}
```

the following method will used by your model when it needs to get the value of start_date attribute this method must be written in the model

Comment: I added this to my users model but it did not convert the start_date. Do I need to call it in my controllers store function somehow?

Comment: @Northify Because you must add **start_date** to your model $fillable property, it requires the field to be mass assignable